# Using cargo to deploy war to remote Jboss7 server

Tags: jboss7.x, cargo, maven-cargo

I would like to use [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) to deploy my maven generated `war` file to a remote JBoss Server that is already running.

I have configured my `pom.xml` like this:

```
    ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>
                <!-- Container configuration -->
                <container>
                    <timeout>300000</timeout> <!-- 5 minutes -->
                    <containerId>jboss71x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>

                <!-- Configuration to use with the container -->
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.hostname><myIP></cargo.hostname>
                        <cargo.jboss.management.port>9999</cargo.jboss.management.port>
                        <cargo.remote.username><myUser></cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password><myPass></cargo.remote.password>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <!-- Deployer configuration -->
                <deployer>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </deployer>

                <!-- Deployables configuration -->
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>de.<myGroup></groupId>
                        <artifactId><myArtifact></artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <pingURL>http://<myIP>:8080/<myContextPath></pingURL>
                        <pingTimeout>60000</pingTimeout>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    ...
```

Of course all variables of the form <`my...`> are filled out with the real values.

If I run this with the maven command:

```
mvn -X cargo:deploy
```

The maven console says:

```
...
Sep 12, 2012 5:06:12 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Sep 12, 2012 5:06:12 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
[DEBUG] [swordCallbackHandler] Responded to a RealmCallback
[DEBUG] [swordCallbackHandler] Responded to a NameCallback
[DEBUG] [swordCallbackHandler] Responded to a PasswordCallback
[INFO] [Boss7xRemoteDeployer] The deployment has failed: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot deploy deployable org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.deployable.JBossWAR[myWar.war]
...
```

On the running JBoss server I can see a logging message in the console like this:

```
17:07:24,197 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "pc09:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen.
```

(sorry for the german inside of the log. It basically says: An existing connection was closed by the remote host.)

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong or how I could get more debug info from cargo to find out what exactly the problem is?

BTW: I have used the JBoss CLI access to that Jboss Server for [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) tests so I am pretty confident that the access to that Jboss server via CLI should be ok.

**EDIT:** 
Seems like I have to undeploy first. To reassure that the access to the CLI works I just connected to it using the `jboss-cli.bat`. Then I just coincidentally undeployed the existing war and after that the deployment via cargo started to work.
(Can I close this question or mark it as resolved in any way?)

Comment: There is also a jboss-as-maven-plugin that will also deploy your application. https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Comment: I had a look at this before but was not able to find any documentation on remote deploying - so I looked further and came across cargo. Does the JBoss plugin support remote deploying?

Comment: Indeed it does. You just have to set the <hostname/> and <port/> in your configuration (https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html). Optionally you can add a username and password too. In future releases you'll be able to pass -Djboss-as.hostname too.

Comment: Thx for the info. I guess I overlooked that.

Comment: Not a problem. Hopefully there should be a new release of it today with some extra goodies :-) (today being 2012-09-14)